# Tokenize with a regex a string composed of a subset of markdown

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I would like to tokenize **with a regex** a strings composed of a subset of markdown, more specifically:

- bold is represented by `**text**`
- italic is represented by `_text_`

So for example the string `a _b_ c **d** _e` should be tokenized as `['a ', 'b', ' c', 'd' '_e']` (NB: to know the type of the token I need to keep each match in a separate group).
I'm able to capture the groups corresponding to the bold and italic with a regex like `/_(.+?)_|\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g`, but how can I extend that regex to also include the "regular" text? Something like *"everything inside `**`, everything inside `_` and all the rest"*.
I've tried adding another case `/_(.+?)_|\*\*(.+?)\*\*|(.*)/g` but of course this will also capture the previous cases.

---

(Fast way to test in the browser console `Array.from('a _b_ c **d** _e'.matchAll(/_(.+?)_|\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g))`)

Comment: My guess is you're going to surpass the limits of a regex pretty shortly. Sounds more like you want an abstract syntax tree parser... Then you get both the parts and the type information, and you can handle things like matching  delimiters, etc.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-parse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicode marker `/(?:\*{2})?_(\p{L}+)_(?:\*{2})?|(?:_)?\*{2}(\p{L}+)\*{2}(?:_)?|([*_\p{L}]+)/gu`:

```js
console.log(Array.from('a _b_ c **d** _e'.matchAll(/(?:\*{2})?_(\p{L}+)_(?:\*{2})?|(?:_)?\*{2}(\p{L}+)\*{2}(?:_)?|([*_\p{L}]+)/gu)))
```

Comment: But in this way I don't have the information about the token type (e.g. I have no idea that "hello" should be italic). Also the last "_test" miss the leading underscore.

Comment: The browser support for `\p` seems also not optimal

Comment: @raxell, updated my answer, for the \p, you are right, it depends on the version of your browser but you can replace it with `[a-zA-Z]`